# Pentaho mail authentication using OAuth2

Tags: authentication, email, oauth-2.0, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to send an email using Pentaho, and I was using simple username/password authentication to login to SMTP server.
Now, I need to switch to modern authentication using **OAuth2 **to get the **token **and send emails.
I've been searching for solutions, and all I found was that username and password are **always required to authenticate to the server.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gybwm.png)

Has anyone tried to use OAuth2 for mail authentication in Pentaho job? or it's not possible to use it in the first place?

I tried to use Rest Client step to authenticate, but it seems like the Mail step still needs SMTP credentials on its own.